# Using iter on an existing iterator in Python: What happens to the iterator?

Tags: python, iterator

The [iter function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) wraps objects like lists or tuples in order to use them as iterators, i.e. one is able to use `next`, for example. For instance,

```
next(iter([1, 2, 3]))
```

returns 1.

What happens internally if the object we pass to `iter` is already an iterator? Does it simply return the original object, i.e. no-op? Or does it produce a new iterator wrapping the original one? And by wrapping I don't mean copying the original iterator, of course.

Comment: any next() will affect all others

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDNR: `iter` returns `obj.__iter_`. It doesn't return `obj` "as is".

The Cpython implementation of `iter` is pretty straightforward:

```
PyObject *
PyObject_GetIter(PyObject *o)
{
    PyTypeObject *t = o->ob_type;
    getiterfunc f = NULL;
    if (PyType_HasFeature(t, Py_TPFLAGS_HAVE_ITER))
        f = t->tp_iter; // <- if it has __iter__, return that
    ....more stuff
```

So when you call `iter(obj)` and `obj.__iter__` exists it just returns that. Most (all?) built-in iterators have `__iter__ = self`, e.g.

```
PyTypeObject PyListIter_Type = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(&PyType_Type, 0)
    "listiterator",                             /* tp_name */
    ....
    PyObject_SelfIter,                          /* tp_iter */
    ....
```

but that's not necessary true for userland objects:

```
class X:
    def __iter__(self):
        return Y()

class Y:
    def __iter__(self):
        return iter('xyz')


a = iter(X())
b = iter(a)
print a is b # False
```

Comment: Wasn't as straightforward as I thought. I guess I got to move the answered mark. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Empirical evidence is nice, but [the docs are pretty explicit](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).

> Iterators are required to have an [`__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) method that returns the iterator object itself

If you implement an object with a `__next__()`, you should have an `__iter__()` method that returns `self`. Breaking this rule means you have an object that isn't an iterator but looks like one, which is a recipie for disaster.